# Debug BizTalk Map Exception generated

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

When I try to debug a BizTalk map I receive the following error:-

> error btm1023: Exception Caught: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

I have previously debugged this map successfully, so therefore something in VS much have changed.  I have already tried:-

1. Deleting temporary asp.net files under C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
2. Deleting files under each of the Visual Studio versions e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
3. Deleting DLLs in bin folder of my project
4. Cleaning my solution

..and none of the above resolves my issue.  Has anyone got a solution to this please as I need to be able to debug a map?

Comment: How are you debugging?  With the Debug option or Attach?  Does the map run successfully otherwise?

Comment: Right click on the map in the solution file, in Visual Studio and "Debug Map".

Comment: Yes, otherwise the map tests successfully, I just can't debug it.

Comment: You can try copying the Map and Schemas to new Solution.  I see you've tried some other suggestions.  Does the map use any External Assemblies?  You can't Debug with Assemblies defined in the Extensions Xml.

Comment: Can you right click and Validate map?  Anything unusual in the xslt that it is generating? Have you tried closing and re-opening Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes the map validates fine.  It's not just one map, all maps I am now unable to debug, so I do not think it is related to the code but a corrupt dll somewhere.  Yes, tried closing and re-opening VS and rebooting - no joy.

Comment: Is the TestMap Input Instance populated?  What happens if you right click and select Test Map?  What version of Visual Studio?  Were there any updates applied to machine/visual studio/biztalk?

Comment: Sorry, only just noticed your reply.  I can test the map without any issues, I just can't debug.  This is visual studio 2010 SP1.  No updates applied as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this be uninstalling Visual Studio completely and then reinstalling it, I can now debug!